# How to update two columns in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

This doesn't work:

```
UPDATE customers SET firstname="John" AND lastname="Smith" WHERE id=1;
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Separate values with commas. `AND` is an logical operator, its place is in `WHERE` and `ON` clauses.

```
UPDATE customers SET firstname="John", lastname="Smith" WHERE id=1;
```