# Update MySQL by deltas - Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I read I can use this:

```
SomeModel.update_all name: 'my name'
```

To make a batch transaction. Is it possible to make this change using the actual value in each row?

Example:

```
some_models
name
'asd'
'qwe'
```

A code that allows me to get:

```
some_models
name
'asd another'
'qwe another'
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this at database level.. Here's how to do it in postgresql

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = column_name || 'yo';
```

and in MySQL(not tested)

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = CONCAT(column_name ,'yo');
```

Comment: another thing, how can I update two fields at once? I mean in SQL?

Comment: thanks, to update several columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427010/how-to-update-two-columns-in-a-mysql-database